# how to add multiple languages to an English website

Tags: multilingual

I am trying to add two additional languages to my website - Chinese, Japanese. User inputs could be in native language, in English or be mixed. E.g. search by product name. Likewise output can be all-English or be in mixed languages, depending on a user's preferences. I already have applicable translations so that is not a problem. It is a data intensive site. It uses web APIs to fetch JSON data objects, and uses angular and backbone, and jquery.

I will appreciate if you possibly refer me to some good books or pages that provide guidance for building multilingual sites. Are there any particular web standards that must be followed by websites and by browsers?

Googling yields a ton of links, but the discussion appears centered around specific packages such as wordpress, joomla, .net, drupal, etc. and appears more around automated translations. It still left me confused about the basics requirements of multilingual sites as I do not use any of these packages.

Thanks a lot.

ps: if you need to leave me a -1, np. But I would very much appreciate a comment as to why - so that it doesn't appear as if you just vented and offered me no opportunity for improvement.

Comment: The problem is that different languages and frameworks have different mechanisms for handling internationalization.  There are further considerations for handling user provided translations, etc.  (note I did not -1 the question).  As the question is stated right now, it's still just asking for preferred list of products...  Just how familiar are you with the differences in the languages?  Reading order is a big issue, as it can affect overall layout of your site.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch I suppose you are right about it being an open-ended question but I have received some good advice here, so, not too bad

Answer (score 0):

Wells... when i need to build a bilingual website i just use a language selector menu and build the whole website in 2 languages (i think this way its more professional) cause usually translators doesnt 100% translate correctly and at the end you just get a bunch of stuff making no sense.

Maybe you could use Google Website Translator gadget for what you trying to do?? its paid service tho, you could use also the plugin for Wordpress http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-language-translator/

Or use the Google Ajax Language API https://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/

Comment: Thanks Nahomy. I am not looking to translate the existing website but to allow for mixed language content in output as well as input fields.

Comment: Seems like you are going to need to build the form section for each language, maybe someone else can help you. And by the way i dont vote negative so no worries for me xD